# match exact digits within string and replace oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, case, case-when

I need to match on an exact set of digits to then replace with a '1' in another column, i can do this with a CASE statement like the following

```
SELECT
  CASE PT_6 WHEN '75' THEN '1' ELSE '' END AS PT_6_1
FROM edrn.pca_patient
WHERE irid = 4395;
```

However the PT_6 column is populated from checkboxes on the application so when multiple checkboxes are selected the data is 86,75,81.

I need a way to pull out the value i enter from the string and replace it with 1 in a different column e.g. PT_6_1. I had played with some REGEXP's but not sure that i can do that within a CASE.

In other columns where this will be needed - They're not all 2 digits, some are 3 so i imagine if i use some form of a LIKE that i could falsely pick up 75 out of 175 for instance

Some sample data and more information, for this example coumn PT_6 there are 6 possible checkboxes. I need each checkboxes in a separate column as either 1 or 0 for ticked or not so the columns are PT_6_1, PT_6_2 and so on.

Current data from 4 records

```
IRID    PT_6
4395    85,75,87
3183    85,87
3219    85
2180    86
```

So say i want 87 to be represented into column PT_6_3 and NULL's if there is no match then the data would be

```
IRID    PT_6_1  PT_6_2  PT_6_3  PT_6_4  PT_6_5  PT_6_6
4395    null    null    1       null    null    null
3183    null    null    1       null    null    null
3219    null    null    null    null    null    null
2180    null    null    null    null    null    null
```

Thanks,
Allan

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result ( as formatted text, not images please) to clarify your need.

Comment: Also I have the feeling that you should normalize the data coming from your app.  CSV is difficult to work with in a database.

Comment: We are moving away from this application. The data is being exported for the new system. The new system is the reason for needing 1's or 0's for 'ticked' or 'unticked'. I'll edit the original post with some sample data

Comment: Updated original post to include sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the original version of the question:

```
SELECT TRIM( BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE( ','||PT_6||',', ',75,', ',1,' ) ) AS PT_6_1
FROM   edrn.pca_patient
WHERE  irid = 4395;
```

In answer to the updated version of the question:

```
SELECT irid,
       CASE WHEN ','||PT_6||',' LIKE '%,75,%' THEN 1 END AS PT_6_contains_75,
       CASE WHEN ','||PT_6||',' LIKE '%,85,%' THEN 1 END AS PT_6_contains_85,
       CASE WHEN ','||PT_6||',' LIKE '%,87,%' THEN 1 END AS PT_6_contains_87
FROM   edrn.pca_patient
```

Comment: In this case perhaps it doesn't matter, but: if the input string uses consecutive commas to mark a NULL, and if a NULL is at the beginning or at the end, this means the actual string PT_6 may begin or end with one or more commas. Those will be "swallowed" by TRIM.

Comment: @mathguy The OP mentioned that this was coming from checkboxes (presumably from a HTTP request) - so assuming that the value on the checkboxes is never an empty string then that situation will, as you said, never occur. However `TRIM` could be replace with `SUBSTR` to only remove the first and last characters.

Comment: Right. Obviously I was happy with your answer (+1) but just wanted to make that clear for anyone who may think of using the same solution for similar, but not identical problems.

Comment: I need it to recognize there's a matching value and put a 1 in a new column, i updated the original post with sample data and desired output

Comment: @phemor Updated to answer your clarified requirements.